# Scikeras ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_30" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 99)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a CNN using the new scikeras KerasRegressor wrapper and am getting a ValueError for my input shape but not in the first layer I don't think.  My input shape is (1, None, 99, 1), so I'm definitely inputting 4 dimensions.

> ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_12'
> (type Sequential).
>
> Input 0 of layer "conv2d_30" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 99)

This is the model I'm using, which is partially from the scikeras documentation:

```
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Any

class MLPRegressor(KerasRegressor):  #https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/notebooks/MLPClassifier_MLPRegressor.html

    def __init__(
        self,
        optimizer="adam",
        optimizer__learning_rate=0.001,
        epochs=200,
        verbose=0,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.verbose = verbose

    def _keras_build_fn(self, compile_kwargs: Dict[str, Any]):
        model = keras.Sequential()
        inp = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 99, 1))
        model.add(inp)
        # for hidden_layer_size in self.hidden_layer_sizes:
        #     layer = keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation="relu")
        #     model.add(layer)
        # out = keras.layers.Dense(1)
        # model.add(out)
        model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(activation = 'relu', filters = 4, kernel_size = (3,3), input_shape = (1, None, 99, 1), padding = 'same')), #building model layers
        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()),
        model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(activation = 'relu', filters = 4, kernel_size = (3,3), padding = 'same')),
        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()),
        model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(activation = 'relu', filters = 4, kernel_size = (3,3), padding = 'same')),
        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()),
        model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(activation = 'relu', filters = 4, kernel_size = (3,3), padding = 'same')),
        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()),
        model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(activation = 'relu', filters = 4, kernel_size = (3,3), padding = 'same')),
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=compile_kwargs["optimizer"])
        return model

from sklearn.datasets import make_regression


reg = MLPRegressor(epochs=20)  # for notebook execution time

# Define a simple linear relationship
# y = np.arange(100)
# X = (y/2).reshape(-1, 1)

# # check score
# reg.fit(X, y)
# # print(reg.score(X, y))

for i in range(0, len(X)):
  result_cnn = reg.fit(X[i], y[i])
  print(result_cnn.summary())

for i in range(0, len(X_test)):
  pred_cnn = result_cnn.predict(X_test[i])
```

The shape is None, as I have varying sizes of inputs, but I don't think that's the issue.  The data is semi-random and generated with a significant portion of my notebook.

Edit:
I thought maybe the issue was from my  X[i] dimensions, so I tried adding a  dimension to them, but got a new error.

For example, I expanded (600, 99)  to (600, 99, 1).

Now I get this error:

> ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'max_pooling2d_37' (type MaxPooling2D).
>
> Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node sequential_15/max_pooling2d_37/MaxPool}} = MaxPoolT=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]' with input shapes: [?,99,1,4].
>
> Call arguments received by layer 'max_pooling2d_37' (type MaxPooling2D):
> • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 99, 1, 4), dtype=float32)

I expanded dimensions using:

```
for i in range(0,len(X)):
  X[i] = np.expand_dims(X[i], -1)
```

How to resolve these errors?

Comment: Can you add the full code with model and data (with data shape)? We can't help you without that.

Comment: Where does you `X` and  `y` come from? Again, please add the *full* code.